# Getting multiple columns selected into variables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am having problems with the following code:

```
/* Cursor */
DECLARE @RelationCursor CURSOR 
SET @RelationCursor = (SELECT [fms].[dbo].[Relation].[RELATIONCODE], [fms].[dbo].[Relation].[COMPANYNAME] INTO @RelationCode, @CompanyName FROM [fms].[dbo].[Relation])

OPEN @RelationCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM @RelationCursor INTO @RelationCode, @CompanyName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    print(@RelationCode)
    print(@CompanyName)

    FETCH NEXT FROM @RelationCursor INTO @RelationCode, @CompanyName
END

CLOSE @RelationCursor
```

I am trying to get `RelationCode` and `Companyname` into `@RelationCode` and `@Companyname` so I can use them in the cursor loop. But I get an error in the `SELECT` query:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spLoadProfits, Line 21
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'.

But the query seems completely fine to me and I can't seem to figure out the problem about this. Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cursor name should not start with `@`, and also you need to deallocate the cursor when you are done with it.

Try this instead:

```
DECLARE @RelationCode int,  -- I guessed the data type, change if needed
        @CompanyName varchar(100)  -- I guessed the data type, change if needed

DECLARE RelationCursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT [fms].[dbo].[Relation].[RELATIONCODE], [fms].[dbo].[Relation].[COMPANYNAME] 
    FROM [fms].[dbo].[Relation]

OPEN RelationCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM RelationCursor INTO @RelationCode, @CompanyName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    print(@RelationCode)
    print(@CompanyName)

    FETCH NEXT FROM RelationCursor INTO @RelationCode, @CompanyName
END

CLOSE RelationCursor
DEALLOCATE RelationCursor;
```